# Integration by Parts: $\int \arcsin(x))dx$

Tags: calculus

$\int \arcsin(x)\mathrm{d}x$

$u=\arcsin(x)$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

$v=\mathrm{d}x$ $\rightarrow$ $v=x$

$\int \arcsin(x)=(\arcsin(x)(x))-\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

$w$-substitution:

$w= 1-x^2$

$\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{-2}=\mathrm{d}x$

this is where I am stuck. Wouldn't I find the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$

and wouldn't that be:

$\arcsin(x)+x\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Comment: Use the $\LaTeX$ command $\texttt{\arcsin}$ to typeset the arcsine function name nicely.

Comment: $\int \arcsin(x)\, dx=(\arcsin(x))(x)-\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, dx$.

Comment: Also, the notation $(arc(sin(x))(x))$ simply makes no sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula of integration by parts is
$$
\int f'(x)g(x)\,dx=f(x)g(x)-\int f(x)g'(x)\,dx
$$
and in your case $f'(x)=1$ (so you can take $f(x)=x$) and $g(x)=\arcsin(x)$.

Thus the correct steps are
$$
\int 1\cdot\arcsin(x)\,dx=x\arcsin(x)-\int x\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx
$$
Now the integral is elementary, because
$$
-\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx=\sqrt{1-x^2}+C
$$
by simple differentiation.

Answer (score 2):

Like you said,
$$\begin{align*}\int \arcsin x\,dx&=x\arcsin x-\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,dx\\[1ex]
&=x\arcsin x+\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{dw}{\sqrt w}&\text{where }w=1-x^2\end{align*}$$
Proceed with the remaining integral, then back-substitute.

Comment: $\int \arcsin(x)\, dx=(\arcsin(x))(x)-\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\, dx$.

Comment: @user236182 yes, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: I am not following you. Do I find the derivative of $arc(sin(x))$

Comment: @Cetshwayo No, you're not doing any differentiation here (aside from what you've done to find $du$ and $dw$. The first line is precisely what you've done via integration by parts. The second line implements the substitution you used.

Comment: yeah i figured it out. I was calculating the derivative again.